# Send value from select to servlet

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, servlets, combobox

I want to get the value from a `select` to a servlet. It works but not correctly.

```
<select name="type" class="txtBox">
    <%while (rs2.next()) {%>
        <%if (!rs2.getString("states").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("inactive")) {%>
            <option value="<%=rs2.getString("loancode").trim()%>">
                <%=rs2.getString("loanname").trim()%>
            </option>
        <%}%>
    <%}%>
</select>
```

this code is after load to browser

```
<select name="type" class="txtBox">
      <option value="VL">veheicle loan</option>
      <option value="HL">housing loan</option>
      <option value="EL">education loan</option>
</select>
```

It works OK, but after save to DB value from combo box saved value not loancode value .saved value is loanname value.

[image]

like this pic i want to save loantype as vehicle loan.but it save as  'veh'(option name first 3 character) i want save as 'VL'(value of option).but i can't imaging how to do this please help me to do this.

*loanename,loancode,loantype is my DB column

**sorry for my bad english

Comment: Tried to add some sense into your question but that last paragraph is impossible to understand.

Comment: i edited it now.sorry for my bad English.can you help me now.

Comment: Show your server-side code, i.e. the code that processes the submitted form.